# Maven build section deduplication

Tags: xml, maven, build

Our application consists of many microservices built by Maven. Their services have following structure:

- Service

  - `service-core` (server side)

    - pom.xml (service-core pom file)
  - `service-client` (client side)

    - pom.xml (service-client pom file)
- `pom.xml` (to inherit dependencies and basic properties)

`core` and `client` have a different stack, hence their build sections do not match. But the build sections of all cores and clients across all services are the same.

We want to deduplicate these build sections to one external file (so when we change something, we do not need to modify it on many places).

---

We have considered some inheritance, but thats not easily possible as `core` and `client` do not share the same build procedure, we are also using Maven modules to build individual service as a whole (parent + all submodules).

Other possibility that we have tried were XML entities + import, but entities are intentionally forbidden in Maven (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3556).

Is there any other possibility?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the difference between `service-core` and `service-client` are those two jar's or war's ? Can you give an example configuration of them? And what are in particular the differences in build section?

Comment: one is plain jar, one is executable jar (Spring boot), there are different plugins (for documentation, different setting for pmd...)

Comment: PMD plugins is checking source code so there is no need to make a difference...Settings for pmd plugin could be defined in pluginManagement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven supports [build profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html):

> Profiles are specified using a subset of the elements available in the POM itself (plus one extra section), and are triggered in any of a variety of ways. They modify the POM at build time, and are meant to be used in complementary sets to give equivalent-but-different parameters for a set of target environments.

In your case there could be a `services` project that contains the profiles declarations for `core` and `client` projects in its POM:

```
+- services
   +- service_1
      +- core
      +- client
   +- service_2_
      +- core
      +- client
   +- service_3
      +- ...
   +- ...
```

#### UPDATE

Without any profile:

```
+- services  ... just aggregators here and below, build here and below only
   +- service_1_builder
      +- core
      +- client
   +- service_2_builder
      +- core
      +- client
   +- service_3_builder
      +- ...
   +- ...
+- main  ... parent containing declarations common to all descendant projects 
   +- cores  ... parent containing declarations for core builds 
      +- service_1
      +- service_2
      +- service_3
      +- ...
   +- clients  ... parent containing declarations for client builds 
      +- service_1
      +- service_2
      +- service_3
      +- ...
```

POM `services` contains:

```
<modules>
  <module>service_1_builder</module>
  <module>service_2_builder</module>
  <module>service_3_builder</module>
  <module>...</module>
</modules>
```

POMs of `services/service_n_builder` contain:

```
<modules>
  <module>core</module>
  <module>client</module>
</modules>
```

POMs of `services/service_n_builder/core` contain:

```
<modules>
  <module>../../../main/cores/service_n</module>
</modules>
```

POMs of `services/service_n_builder/client` contain:

```
<modules>
  <module>../../../main/clients/service_n</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: This would make it impossible to build the project as a whole (from parent), because it would force me to set both profiles at the same time..

Comment: @malejpavouk You're right. See the update to my answer.